# How can I connect to a remote cassandra db using Flask?

Tags: python, flask, cassandra

I can't find any info on Internet about how I can tell my flask app which port it should look at when trying to connect to Cassandra.

From their official website I got:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['CASSANDRA_HOSTS'] = ['127.0.0.1']
app.config['CASSANDRA_KEYSPACE'] = "cqlengine"
db = CQLAlchemy(app)
```

I've tried to add the port to the host with colon or comma and yet nothing. Obviously by default it tries to connect to 9042 and fails miserably.

Comment: I would provide the stack trace

Comment: I don't think it's helpful in any way. I just need to know how to add the port to the app configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the port with the following code:

```
app.config['CASSANDRA_SETUP_KWARGS'] = {'port': 90422}
```

The *CASSANDRA_SETUP_KWARGS* configuration value is a parameter of the cassandra.cqlengine.connection.setup method. More information on that here: https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/cqlengine/connection.html

You can change any Cluster variables with the *CASSANDRA_SETUP_KWARGS* config. See the following documentation for what configurations are available for the Cluster object: https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/cluster.html#cassandra.cluster.Cluster